# Extract colnames from a nested list of data.frames

Tags: r, dataframe, nested

I have a nested list of data.frames, what is the easiest way to get the column names of all data.frames?

Example:

```
d = data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 1:3, c = 1:3)

l = list(a = d, list(b = d, c = d))
```

Result:

```
$a
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$b
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$c
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are already a couple of answers. But let me leave another approach. I used `rapply2()` in the rawr package.

```
devtools::install_github('raredd/rawr')
library(rawr)
library(purrr)

rapply2(l = l, FUN = colnames) %>% 
flatten

$a
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$b
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$c
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is a base R solution.

You can define a customized function to flatten your nested list (which can deal nested list of ***any depths***, e.g., more than 2 levels), i.e.,

```
flatten <- function(x){  
  islist <- sapply(x, class) %in% "list"
  r <- c(x[!islist], unlist(x[islist],recursive = F))
  if(!sum(islist))return(r)
  flatten(r)
}
```

and then use the following code to achieve the colnames

```
out <- Map(colnames,flatten(l))
```

such that

```
> out
$a
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$b
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$c
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

**Example with a deeper nested list**

```
l <- list(a = d, list(b = d, list(c = list(e = list(f= list(g = d))))))
> l
$a
  a b c
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3

[[2]]
[[2]]$b
  a b c
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3

[[2]][[2]]
[[2]][[2]]$c
[[2]][[2]]$c$e
[[2]][[2]]$c$e$f
[[2]][[2]]$c$e$f$g
  a b c
1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3 3
```

and you will get

```
> out
$a
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$b
[1] "a" "b" "c"

$c.e.f.g
[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is an attempt to do this as Vectorized as possible,

```
i1 <- names(unlist(l, TRUE, TRUE))
#[1] "a.a1" "a.a2" "a.a3" "a.b1" "a.b2" "a.b3" "a.c1" "a.c2" "a.c3" "b.a1" "b.a2" "b.a3" "b.b1" "b.b2" "b.b3" "b.c1" "b.c2" "b.c3" "c.a1" "c.a2" "c.a3" "c.b1" "c.b2" "c.b3" "c.c1" "c.c2" "c.c3"
i2 <- names(split(i1, gsub('\\d+', '', i1)))
#[1] "a.a" "a.b" "a.c" "b.a" "b.b" "b.c" "c.a" "c.b" "c.c"
```

We can now split `i2` on everything before the dot, which will give,

```
split(i2, sub('\\..*', '', i2))

#    $a
#    [1] "a.a" "a.b" "a.c"

#    $b
#    [1] "b.a" "b.b" "b.c"

#    $c
#    [1] "c.a" "c.b" "c.c"
```

To get them fully cleaned, we need to loop over and apply a simple regex,

```
 lapply(split(i2, sub('\\..*', '', i2)), function(i)sub('.*\\.', '', i))
```

which gives,

> ```
> $a
> [1] "a" "b" "c"
>
> $b
> [1] "a" "b" "c"
>
> $c
> [1] "a" "b" "c"
> ```

**The Code compacted**

```
i1 <- names(unlist(l, TRUE, TRUE))
i2 <- names(split(i1, gsub('\\d+', '', i1)))
final_res <- lapply(split(i2, sub('\\..*', '', i2)), function(i)sub('.*\\.', '', i))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
d = data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 1:3, c = 1:3)

l = list(a = d, list(b = d, c = d))

foo <- function(x, f){
    if (is.data.frame(x)) return(f(x))
    lapply(x, foo, f = f)
}

foo(l, names)
```

The crux here is that `data.frames` actually are special list, so it's important what to test for.

Small explanation: what needs to be done here is a recursion, since with every element you might look at either a dataframe, so you want to decide if you apply the `names` or go deeper into the recursion and call `foo` again.

Comment: The problem is that foo(l, names) also returns a nested list

Comment: I don't. Not sure, what you did differently.

Comment: You can add `unlist()` at the end, but I am not sure if this is what you want.

Answer (score 2):

First create l1, a nested list with only the colnames

```
l1 <- lapply(l, function(x) if(is.data.frame(x)){
  list(colnames(x)) #necessary to list it for the unlist() step afterwards
}else{
  lapply(x, colnames)
})
```

Then unlist l1

```
unlist(l1, recursive=F)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way using `purrr` functions `map_depth` and `vec_depth`

```
library(purrr)

return_names <- function(x) {
   if(inherits(x, "list"))
     return(map_depth(x, vec_depth(x) - 2, names))
    else return(names(x))
}

map(l, return_names)

#$a
#[1] "a" "b" "c"

#[[2]]
#[[2]]$b
#[1] "a" "b" "c"

#[[2]]$c
#[1] "a" "b" "c"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using an external package, this is also straightforward with `rrapply()` in the `rrapply`-package (and works for arbitrary levels of nesting):

```r
library(rrapply)

rrapply(l, classes = "data.frame", f = colnames, how = "flatten")
#> $a
#> [1] "a" "b" "c"
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] "a" "b" "c"
#> 
#> $c
#> [1] "a" "b" "c"

## deeply nested list
l2 <- list(a = d, list(b = d, list(c = list(e = list(f = list(g = d))))))

rrapply(l2, classes = "data.frame", f = colnames, how = "flatten")
#> $a
#> [1] "a" "b" "c"
#> 
#> $b
#> [1] "a" "b" "c"
#> 
#> $g
#> [1] "a" "b" "c"
```