# How can I get the column names that are resulting in the "undefined columns selected" error?

Tags: r

I got this error in a piece of code where I subset a data frame using a list with the columns I wish to mantain. I have and managed to find the problematic column (column name was mispelled in the list) and solved the problem.

But to accomplish that, I had to check each entry in the list, checking column names one by one to find it.

Is there a way (some function, perhaps) to make R show what columns are undefined?

Answer (score 1):

You may try `purrr` functions `map_depth` and `vec_depth`. Learned here [Extract colnames from a nested list of data.frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59820309/extract-colnames-from-a-nested-list-of-data-frames). Credits to Ronak Shah.

```
library(purrr)

return_names <- function(x) {
   if(inherits(x, "list"))
     return(map_depth(x, vec_depth(x) - 2, names))
    else return(names(x))
}

map(yourlist, return_names)
```